# To implement a member registration or login page in the MFA method

Tags: reactjs

To implement a member registration or login page in the MFA method

I don't know what ngnix is, but an acquaintance told me to use it and told me to do pass routing using it, but I'm not sure what you mean.

I don't know what ngnix is, but an acquaintance told me to use it and told me to do pass routing using it, but I'm not sure what you mean.